# File upload issue at struts action testing

Tags: java, servlets, junit, struts, apache-poi

I would like to setup unit tests over struts actions which are processing Excel sheets uploaded from web form.
I picked **strutstest** library and used it together with **cactus** framework.
Cactus doesn't have multipart request option on its own. So I used one more library and recommended workaround from cactus site.

```
public class ActionTest extends CactusStrutsTestCase {

NVPair[] hdrs = new NVPair[1];
    //this method prepares request
public void beginFileUpload(WebRequest req) {
    NVPair[] opts = { new NVPair("MAX_FILE_SIZE", "20485760") };
    NVPair[] file = { new NVPair("myFile", "D://temp//TEST.xls") };     
    try {
        byte[] data = Codecs.mpFormDataEncode(opts, file, hdrs);
        InputStream i = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        req.setUserData(i);
        req.setContentType(hdrs[0].getValue());
        i.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here *NVPair* and *Codecs* are classes from recommended library.
And I'm getting the following exception when file data is passed to apache POI framework on server side:

```
POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(istTest);
...
java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0xC8001A0031006C00, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0
```

As I understand, file data has been  corrupted, because multipart request was not encoded properly. 
The file I use is formed well. I tested it in different way with **apache commons httpclient** library:

```
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   try {
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9080" +
               "/retrieveData.do?background=yes");

       FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("D://temp//TEST.xls"));

       //MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(); this no param constructor also leads to exception 
       MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, "47436622^%2824349", Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
       reqEntity.addPart("bin", bin);
       httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

       if (resEntity != null) {
           System.out.println("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
       }
       EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
   } finally {
       try { httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
   }
```

But this approach tests connection. I need to take advantage of cactus to evaluate action execution results.
Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't corrupted on the client side? i.e. Can POI open it without error on the client?

Comment: yes, file is not corrupted, it is transferred correctly via browser  and is recognized by POI on server. Though I can not check it on client, since I use POI on server. 
also one more thing came to me: as you see from my post this file transferred via http perfectly, if I use apache commons httpclient lib and open connection by myself. So it could happen that it's cactus bug to open connection and send data.